# How can i send Mail message in asp .net to Multiple Address (Address,Subject,Body Unique for each mail) at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.Body = "";
msg.To.Add(...);
msg.To.Add(...);


SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Send(msg);
```

This sends the same subject and body to multiple address. 
However I want unique mail to be send to each.

Any solution other than looping through?

Comment: If you have different subjects, bodies and email addresses to send to, how do expect to do this without a loop of some description?  Even with `IEnumerator` you'll have to loop through...

Comment: Also, what have you tried in order to achieve this?

Comment: Is it possible,kind of creating collection of MailMessage and hit the smtp.Send() at once. I just dont want to loop through smtp.Send()

Comment: Why don't you want to loop through smtp.Send()? What bad things do you think are going to happen if you do that?

Comment: Looping 1000 times and hitting smtp.Send() is int a great idea. It makes the process slower. So looking for alternatives that could avoid it.

Comment: Have you tried ` msg.CC.Add(...);`

Answer (score 0):

In the `msg.To.Add(...)`, you will want to add a new `MailAddress` for each person who will receive the mail message...

```
foreach(string address in addressList) msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(address))
...
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Send(msg);
```

If you have these in a list, then you'll need to split them into a `List<string>`.

If you make your software that bit more intelligent, you can test to see who's getting what messages and, perhaps, roll them all up into few actual email.  Draw yourself a Venn diagram and work it out.

Also, to reduce the size of your message and hide the email address list from other users of your service, you could consider using the `Bcc` field instead...

```
foreach(string address in addressList) msg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(address))
```

Answer (score 0):

For unique email address you may have to call Mail function everytime with different email subject etc..

You can use `SendEmail(....)` with different detail and call it..

Sample

```
//call function
 SendEmail("info@domainname.com", emailSubject, emailBody, isHtml);

 public static void SendEmail(string to, string subject, string message, bool isHtml)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a new message
                var mail = new MailMessage();

                // Set the to and from addresses.
                // The from address must be your GMail account
                mail.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@domainname.com", "Don't Reply");
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

                // Define the message
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;
                mail.Body = message;

                // Create a new Smpt Client using Google's servers
                var mailclient = new SmtpClient();
                //mailclient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";//ForGmail
                mailclient.Host = "outlook.office365.com";
                mailclient.Port = 587; //ForGmail
               // mailclient.Port = 25;

                // This is the critical part, you must enable SSL
                //mailclient.EnableSsl = true;//ForGmail
                mailclient.EnableSsl = true;
                mailclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                // Specify your authentication details
                mailclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("no-reply@domainname.com", "password");

                mailclient.Send(mail);
                mailclient.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }
```